# Drop\stop mobile data connection (non-wifi) by conditions

Tags: mobile-data

Can I set Android 4.4.2 to drop mobile data connection once a data limit set by me is reach within a period?

Which version of Android has this feature?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's already been answered in detail (much more details than your short one-liner) at e.g. [How to control, monitor and limit bandwidth usage?](/q/86563/16575). And this feature was introduced with Android 4 aka ICS aka Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: @pop if you're comfortable with third party apps you could try 3g watchdog which allows you to set custom periods like 1 day, week etc then switch off mobile data altogether...

Answer (score 0):

Settings only available after you turn on mobile data, it's under settings-->data usage.